# Page redirection issue in Yii

Tags: php, yii

i have a problem in my application which is built in Yii... when i want to visit a link that show me an error in FireFox as..

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

and in chrome it says...

> This webpage has a redirect loop

one thing more it is working fine on local machine; no issues but the above error is on live server...

Now what is the main issue here..?

Comment: is there any redirect inside your page that working wrong? well it's obvious that there is, but is it in your controller or somewhere else(config maybe)?

Comment: yeah u were right @llamerr... i searched my concerned controllers and found a big blunder where i was redirecting the page from my home controller action... which first comes on index from site and then was supposed to go to my specified function in home controller... which was an infinite loop... i removed that function and placed it in another controller... now it is working fine...

Comment: OH..!!! it still has the problem in firefox... in chrome it is ok... why..?

Comment: I recommend you to debug this so you can find why it is redirect over and over again.

Comment: do you submitting form and then redirect user somewhere? maybe you have onclick function for submit button with ajax inside and not returning false?

Comment: does the application have authentication and authorization issues that you are dealing with in the code. You know what I mean -- access control?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the action 'login' is not allowed to be viewed by any users. Yii's default behavior when a user tries to access a member-only page is to redirect it to the login page, and since your login action is not allowed to guest users, Yii is redirecting again to the login page thus resulting in an endless loop and too-many-redirect error
>
> Check your accessRules() function on the controller class, "UserController.php" in your case.
>   You need to let "Guest" user or ANY user to perform the action, "actionLogin()" in this case.
>
> just add 'login' to "actions array" and check "users array" value is '*'

```
// FILE = WebRoot/protected/controllers/UserController.php

//...
public function accessRules()
        {
                return array(
                        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                                'actions'=>array('index','view','login'),
                                'users'=>array('*'),
        //...
        }
//...
```

> you may have this problem when you delete the default login and then try to create your own,this may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After few days fighting with loop redirect it was solved in non sexy way, but it works

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') ) echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.Yii::app()->createUrl('url/goes/there').'">' ; 
else $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('url/goes/there'));
```